# Avoid 'npm install'?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

**Context**

I have a .NET project and we use some npm packages for the UI. I use a pre-built check if the folder `node_modules` does not exist, run the command `npm install`.

When committing an update to `package.json`, `npm install` will not trigger for other people who are updating the repository. Because `node_modules` exists on their machine which leads to errors like `Can't resolve...`.

**Question(s)**

Is the folder check obsolete? Is `npm install` smart enough to download only the necessary things and not all the dependencies? Or do i need a hash check on `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no harm in running `npm install` multiple times as it will simply not do any operation in case there's nothing to do.

You don't need to check for the `node_modules` folder. `npm` will download and update any dependencies that are missing.

It's also important to run `npm install` since other machines may be running different systems and the dependencies may need to be compiled differently.

You can hash check `package.json` and/or `package-lock.json` for caching purposes, but it's not really necessary.